# How to pass List[String] to select or selectExpr in spark when string contains an UDF as well

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, hadoop2

I have List[String] like below

```
val colList = List(verifyLength($"col1", lit(0), lit(0), lit("RJ"), lit(9)).as("col1"), verifyLength($"col2", lit(0), lit(0), lit("RJ"), lit(16)).as("col2"))
```

When am trying to apply select on data frame like below

```
val selDataDf = df.select(colList.head, colList.tail: _*)
```

am getting exception saying - `` org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`verifyLength($"col1", lit(0), lit(0), lit("RJ"), lit(9)).as("col1")`' given input columns: ``

And If I pass the string as it is like below, It's giving me the result of select statement.

```
val selDataDf = df.select(verifyLength($"col1", lit(0), lit(0), lit("RJ"), lit(9)).as("col1"), verifyLength($"col2", lit(0), lit(0), lit("RJ"), lit(16)).as("col2"))
```

> Note: "verifyLength" is an user defined udf.

Comment: `col1`  exist as a column in `df` ?

Comment: Yeah, It does exist in df.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a reason why it was not working,

you can pass List[String] like below:

```
val detailsList = List(verifyLength(col1, 0, 0, 'RJ', 9) as col1, verifyLength(col2, 0, 0, 'RJ', 9) as col2)
spark.udf.register("verifyLength", verifyLengthCheck _)
 val df1= df.selectExpr(detailsList:_*)
```

Please follow the below url :[enter link description here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/Dataset.html)